# Border radius on button group spanning two rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am using the following radius buttons in bootstrap but would like to modify to show the radio check boxes and also the second button to have border-radius on the right side and the 3th to have it on the left side. Right now the first one have border-radius on the top left and bottom left ant the forth one have on the top right and bottom right.

```
<div class="btn-group lx-toggle-big col-sm-12 col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons">                 
    <label class="btn active col-xs-6" for="option-0">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn col-xs-6" for="option-1">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Option 2
    </label>                
    <label class="btn col-xs-6" for="option-3">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn col-xs-6" for="option-4">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Option 2
    </label>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lx-toggle-big > .btn {
  border: 1px solid #00a0dd;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding:25px 0px 25px 50px;
}
.lx-toggle-big > .btn.active,
.lx-toggle-big > .btn:active {
  background: #f5f7fa;

}
```

Comment: the radio box are shown in your provided codes, i put it in jsfiddle to check https://jsfiddle.net/f5cegnuu/

Answer (score 0):

Just split your button group in half:

```
</div>
<div class="btn-group lx-toggle-big col-sm-12 col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons">
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rd4o92kn/)**